# Is this a counterexample for the Burnside's Theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The following text is trying to solve the number of distinct ways to color a square by two colors B and W :

[image]

The above text considers "the number of distinct ways to color a square by two colors B and W" as the number of distinct orbits. But according to the same book :

> If $G$ acts on a set $X$ and $x,y∈X$, then $x$ is said to be $G$-equivalent to $y$ if there exists a $g∈G$ such that $gx=y$. We write $x∼_Gy$ or $x∼y$ if two elements are $G$-equivalent.
>
> If $X$ is a $G$-set, then each partition of $X$ associated with $G$-equivalence is called an orbit of $X$ under $G$. We will denote the orbit that contains an element $x$ of $X$ by $O_x$.
>
> Example 6. Let $G$ be the permutation group defined by $G = {\{(1), (123), (132), (45), (123)(45), (132)(45)}\}$ and $X ={\{1,2,3,4,5}\}$. Then $X$ is a $G$-set. The orbits are $O_1 = O_2 = O_3 = 
> {\{1,2,3}\}$ and $O_4 = O_5 ={\{4,5}\}$.

My question is: In the case of coloring a square, elements of an orbit $O_x$ means the elements of $\widetilde X$ such that $gx=x$ or $x∼x$ because it includes the elements (maps) that doesn't changes coloring-arrangement. But original definition of orbit as well as a proof of the Burnside's Theorem in the same book says any $y\in \widetilde X$ such that $x∼y$ which in coloring example means "the maps such that if some rigid motion acts the result is another map" which means number of distinct orbits is $1$. Is this a counterexample for the Burnside's Theorem?

A clear simple explanation would be much appreciated.

PS - Source is the book Abstract Algebra by T. W. Judson.

Comment: I think you are saying that if we consider $G$ acting on $X = \{1,2,3,4\}$ then there is one orbit, which is correct. In the text you have posted, we are counting the orbits of the permutation group $\widetilde G$ acting on the set $\widetilde X$ of functions from $X$ into $Y = \{B,W\}$.

Comment: @ZoeH: I meant $\widetilde X$. For any map in $\widetilde X$ there is an element of $D_4$ such that action of that permutation results in another map in $\widetilde X$. So all maps are in one class, not 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, that there are six ways to color, is correct, since the only possible colorings are

1) All vertices colored black.

2) All vertices colored white.

3) One vertex black, three white.

4) One vertex white, three black.

5) diagonally opposite two vertices black, other white.

6) Adjacent two vertices are black, other two white.

The problem you may be facing is *understanding equivalent colorings* or understanding *orbit* of a coloring.

Label the vertices by $x,y,z,w$. Then in the coloring of vertices by black and white, what are possible ways?

$x$ can be B or W, $y$ can be $B$ or $W$, and so on. Thus, *initially*, we can do $2.2.2.2$ colorings.

We want to say, among them, *which are different*? Here, you are saying *two colorings are same if (and only if) one can be obtained from other by rotation or reflection* (i.e. by applying group element in the group of symmetries of square).

For example, following labelling (one black, other white) were different in beginning, but after taking group action, they are coming in same orbit, i.e. they are equivalent. 
[image]

With *this* understanding of *same or different* colorings, the answer, that there are six different colorings, is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Yes, 'manually' counting ways of distinct coloring results in 6. So that's why I wrote *counterexample*: By theorem of Burnside it results 1. That's the problem!

Comment: But the page of book also shows "six" ways, by Burnside.

Comment: Yes, by changing the definition of "orbit". In Burnside's Theorem, elements of an orbit are those have a relation that I have copied it in light-brown section of the OP.

Comment: For any map in X˜ there is an element of D_4 such that action of that permutation results in another map in X˜. So all maps are in **one** class, not 6.

Comment: "two colorings are in same orbit" means "they are equivalent (by some action of group)". What is the equivalence you have taken here? We can say in many ways - "when two colorings are same". In your question: you are saying - "two colorings are equivalent if one comes from other by action of group element". With THIS equivalence (or group action), we should count orbits "manually" which is 6, and also by Burnside it is 6.

Comment: Your last comment, try to understand "For any map in X˜ there is an element of D_4 such that action of that permutation results in another map in X˜." this "another" doesn't mean "every other" but "some other".

Comment: I completely understand what you mean! "every other" consists with the original definition of the orbit. Saying "some other" is trying to change the definition of the orbit which says **any** $y\in X$ such that gx=y. Reason for change of definition is consistency of Burnside with manually counting. please see the example 6 also.

Comment: The standard definition of $x,y$ being in same orbit: $x,y$ are in same orbit **if** there exists $g\in G$ such that $g.x=y$. The standard definition doesn't says "all $x,y$ are in same orbit". (Otherwise, what is the point in this definition; nothing is defined actually here if all are in same orbit).

Comment: To understand the confusion, let us pose this problem: I have two squares, in one "all vertices are black", in other, "all vertices are white". Tell me whether they are in same or different orbit, according to whatever your definition is.

Comment: Your last comment completely reset my mind! Now I understand all what were going on; I didn't see coloring! Thanks a lot for your help and patience. :)

Comment: You are welcome L.G.